# Cumulative gaussian distribuation and normal distribuation

Tags: c#, distribution, gaussian

I made this code

```
    #region const
    private double e = 2.7182;
    private double pi = 3.1415;
    #endregion

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double sr = double.Parse(srednia.Text);
        double od = double.Parse(odchylenie.Text);
        Random randVar = new Random();

        chart1.Series.Add("Gauss");
        chart1.Series["Gauss"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column;
        NextGaussian(sr, od);
    }

    private void NextGaussian(double mean, double stdDev)
    {

        for (double i = 3 - 2 * 3; i <= 3; i = i + 0.1)
        {
            var r_normalny = (1 / (stdDev * Math.Sqrt(2 * pi)) * Math.Pow(e, ((-(i - mean) * (i - mean)) / 2 * (stdDev * stdDev))));
            chart1.Series["Gauss"].Points.AddXY(i, r_normalny);
        }
    }
}
```

}

but I don't know it works well.. and i have problem with cumulative distribution. I found the formula for calculating this but nothing works ..

Comment: No i've made this in other way. I used MathNet Numerics library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I have made something like this. I added all variables for change. Normal, cumulative for poisson distribution. Works perfectly.